# uploading pictures in application and saving path in database for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i m stuck with uploading 3pictures, please suggest how can i move ahead
if you want i can email or upload my full solution for you guys

**below is few detail:**

**My Controller:**

```
namespace TiresalesClaim.Controllers

{

    public class TsiclaimsController : Controller

    {
        private TiresalesClaimContext db = new TiresalesClaimContext();

        // GET: Tsiclaims
        public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search, int? page)
        {
            //  var claims = db.Tsiclaims.Include(d => d.disposition).ToList();

            if (searchBy == "DistributorName")
            {
                return View(db.Tsiclaims.Where(x => x.DistributorName.Contains(search) || search == null)
                    .ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));
            }
            else
                if (searchBy == "TyreSize")
                {
                    return View(db.Tsiclaims.Where(x => x.TyreSize.Contains(search) || search == null)
                        .ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));
                }
                else
                    if (searchBy == "TyreBrand")
                    {
                        return View(db.Tsiclaims.Where(x => x.TyreBrand.Contains(search) || search == null)
                            .ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));
                    }
                    else
                        if (searchBy == "Disposition")
                        {
                            return View(db.Tsiclaims.Where(x => x.DispositionAsPerTSI.Contains(search) || search == null)
                                .ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return View(db.Tsiclaims.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));
                        }

        }

        public ActionResult OrderByDistributorName(int? page)
        {
            var claim = from c in db.Tsiclaims
                        orderby c.DistributorName ascending
                        select c;
            return View((claim).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));
        }

        public ActionResult OrderBySize(int? page)
        {
            var claim = from c in db.Tsiclaims
                        orderby c.TyreSize ascending
                        select c;
            return View((claim).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));
        }

        public ActionResult OrderByBrand(int? page)
        {
            var claim = from c in db.Tsiclaims
                        orderby c.TyreBrand ascending
                        select c;
            return View((claim).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));
        }

        public ActionResult OrderByDisposition(int? page)
        {
            var claim = from c in db.Tsiclaims
                        orderby c.DispositionAsPerTSI descending
                        select c;
            return View((claim).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));
        }
        public ActionResult OrderByDate(int? page)
        {
            var claim = from c in db.Tsiclaims
                        orderby c.ClaimRecDate descending
                        select c;
            return View((claim).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));
        }

        // GET: Tsiclaims/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Tsiclaim tsiclaim = db.Tsiclaims.Find(id);
            if (tsiclaim == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tsiclaim);
        }

        // GET: Tsiclaims/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            TableDbContext tdb = new TableDbContext();

            ViewBag.distributor = new SelectList(tdb.DistributorNames, "Name", "Name");
            ViewBag.size = new SelectList(tdb.TyreSizes, "Name", "Name");
            ViewBag.brand = new SelectList(tdb.TyreBrands, "Name", "Name");
            ViewBag.Dispo = new SelectList(tdb.DispositionAsPerTSIs, "Name", "Name");

            return View();
        }

        // POST: Tsiclaims/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,DistributorName,ClaimRecDate,State,Country,TelNo,FaxNo,Email,TyreSize,TyreBrand,TyreSerialNo,RemainingTreadDept,TreadWear,DefectAsPerDistributor,TypeofTyreWear,DefectAsPerTSI,DispositionAsPerTSI,ClaimValueAwarded,InspectedBy,Picture1,Picture2,Picture3")] Tsiclaim tsiclaim)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Tsiclaims.Add(tsiclaim);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(tsiclaim);
        }

        // GET: Tsiclaims/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            TableDbContext tdb = new TableDbContext();

            ViewBag.distributor = new SelectList(tdb.DistributorNames, "Name", "Name");
            ViewBag.size = new SelectList(tdb.TyreSizes, "Name", "Name");
            ViewBag.brand = new SelectList(tdb.TyreBrands, "Name", "Name");
            ViewBag.Dispo = new SelectList(tdb.DispositionAsPerTSIs, "Name", "Name");

            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Tsiclaim tsiclaim = db.Tsiclaims.Find(id);
            if (tsiclaim == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tsiclaim);
        }

        // POST: Tsiclaims/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,DistributorName,ClaimRecDate,State,Country,TelNo,FaxNo,Email,TyreSize,TyreBrand,TyreSerialNo,RemainingTreadDept,TreadWear,DefectAsPerDistributor,TypeofTyreWear,DefectAsPerTSI,DispositionAsPerTSI,ClaimValueAwarded,InspectedBy,Picture1,Picture2,Picture3")] Tsiclaim tsiclaim)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tsiclaim).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(tsiclaim);
        }

        // GET: Tsiclaims/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Tsiclaim tsiclaim = db.Tsiclaims.Find(id);
            if (tsiclaim == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tsiclaim);
        }

        // POST: Tsiclaims/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Tsiclaim tsiclaim = db.Tsiclaims.Find(id);
            db.Tsiclaims.Remove(tsiclaim);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    } 
}
```

**My Create Page:**

```
@model TiresalesClaim.Models.Tsiclaim


@

{

    ViewBag.Title = "Create";

}

@using (Html.BeginForm())

{


@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @*<h1>Tire Sales International</h1>*@
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>*@

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DistributorName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DistributorName, (SelectList)ViewBag.distributor, "Select Distributor")

                @*@Html.DropDownList("DistributorName", new List<SelectListItem> {
               new SelectListItem{Text="Al Alaly Tyre", Value="Al Alaly Tyre"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="Jilphar", Value="Jilphar"}
           }, "Select Distributor Name")*@
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DistributorName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DistributorName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClaimRecDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClaimRecDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClaimRecDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TelNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TelNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TelNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FaxNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FaxNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FaxNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TyreSize, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TyreSize, (SelectList)ViewBag.size, "Select Tyre Size")

                @*@Html.DropDownList("TyreSize", new List<SelectListItem> {
               new SelectListItem{Text="GD 1200r24 20pr HF702", Value="GD 1200r24 20pr HF702"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="GD 1200r24 20pr GD122", Value="GD 1200r24 20pr GD122"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="TF 1200r24 20pr TF801", Value="TF 1200r24 20pr TF801"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="TF 1200r24 20pr TF580", Value="TF 1200r24 20pr TF580"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="YG 1200r24 20pr FH326", Value="YG 1200r24 20pr FH326"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="GD 315/80r22.5 18pr GD660", Value="GD 315/80r22.5 18pr GD660"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="GD 315/80r22.5 18pr GD768", Value="GD 315/80r22.5 18pr GD768"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="YG 315/80r22.5 18pr FH158", Value="YG 315/80r22.5 18pr FH158"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="YG 315/80r22.5 18pr FH159", Value="YG 315/80r22.5 18pr FH159"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="GD 385/65r22.5 20pr GD022", Value="GD 385/65r22.5 20pr GD022"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="YG 385/65r22.5 20pr FH538", Value="YG 385/65r22.5 20pr FH538"},
           }, "Select Tyre Size")*@
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TyreSize, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TyreSize, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TyreBrand, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TyreBrand, (SelectList)ViewBag.brand, "Select Tyre Brand")

                @*@Html.DropDownList("TyreBrand", new List<SelectListItem> {
               new SelectListItem{Text="GreenDragon Brand Tyre", Value="GreenDragon Brand Tyre"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="Tuffstone Brand Tyre", Value="Tuffstone Brand Tyre"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="Young Brand Tyre", Value="Young Brand Tyre"}
           }, "Select Tyre Brand")*@
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TyreBrand, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TyreBrand, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TyreSerialNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TyreSerialNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TyreSerialNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RemainingTreadDept, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RemainingTreadDept, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RemainingTreadDept, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TreadWear, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TreadWear, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TreadWear, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DefectAsPerDistributor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DefectAsPerDistributor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefectAsPerDistributor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeofTyreWear, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TypeofTyreWear, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeofTyreWear, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DefectAsPerTSI, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DefectAsPerTSI, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefectAsPerTSI, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DispositionAsPerTSI, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.DispositionAsPerTSI,(SelectList)ViewBag.Dispo, "Select Disposition")

                @*@Html.DropDownList("DispositionAsPerTSI", new List<SelectListItem> {
               new SelectListItem{Text="Pass", Value="Pass"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="Fail", Value="Fail"}
           }, "Select Disposition As Per TSI")*@


                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DispositionAsPerTSI, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DispositionAsPerTSI, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClaimValueAwarded, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClaimValueAwarded, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClaimValueAwarded, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Picture1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Picture1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Picture1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Picture1"/>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Picture2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Picture2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Picture2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Picture3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Picture3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Picture3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @*<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />*@
                <input type="image" src="~/Icons/Save.png" alt="Submit" width="40" height="40">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>}<div><a href="@Url.Action("Index")"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Icons/go-back-icon.png")" width="50" />Back</a></div>@section Scripts {@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")}
```

**My Model:**

```
namespace TiresalesClaim.Models

{

    public class Tsiclaim

    {

        [Key]

        [DisplayName("Claim Ref#")]

        public int Id { get; set; }

        //[Key]

        //[Range(1,999999)]
        //public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Distributor Name")]
        public string DistributorName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayName("Claim Rec Date")]
        public DateTime ClaimRecDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("State")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [DisplayName("Tel #")]
        public string TelNo { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Fax #")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string FaxNo { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Tyre Size")]
        public string TyreSize { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Tyre Brand")]
        public string TyreBrand { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        //public string PlyRating { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Tyre Serial #")]
        public string TyreSerialNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Rmaining Tread Dept")]
        public decimal RemainingTreadDept { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("% Tread Wear")]
        public decimal TreadWear { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Defect As Per Distributor")]
        public string DefectAsPerDistributor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Type of Tyre Wear")]
        public string TypeofTyreWear { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Defect As Per TSI")]
        public string DefectAsPerTSI { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Disposition As Per TSI")]
        public string DispositionAsPerTSI { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("% Claim Value Awarded")]
        public decimal ClaimValueAwarded { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Inspected By")]
        public string InspectedBy { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public string Picture1 { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public string Picture2 { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public string Picture3 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Remarks")]
        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        //[NotMapped]
        //public virtual DispositionAsPerTSI disposition { get; set; }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the file data from object containing the file data, i.e. HttpPostedFileBase.  You can then get the data and the fully qualified name/path and save them separately as needed.

See this link for an example: [Uploading a File (Or Files) With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/)

Here is a quick example:

VIEW:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
    <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />
    <input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, but i tried its crashing all, can you apply these changes in View, Controller and Model so i can just copy and past. maybe i m making some mistake.
also what will happen to pictures when i click edit button, can i change them or what will happen.
one more thing when i press edit button my date gets null how can make sure it remember the date entered, even if i make date as display only when i press save it takes date as null and my application gives null error